# Where do I ask about Android device libraries?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Specifically:

> Q: How do you manually remove an installed library from an Android device
>
> Text: I have been developing an Android application in which the name of a native library has changed. The original library (we will call liba.so) has compiled JNI code in it that has been changed in the new library (we will call libb.so). However, when I push the application that is now using libb.so, the device with liba.so on it is still executing the code in liba.so NOT the code in libb.so. Even weirder, the device with liba.so on it is executing only this one JNI function in liba.so, and everything else in libb.so. However, a second device that never has liba.so on it is properly executing the code in libb.so. I have confirmed that liba.so is no where in the Java files, and is not even being compiled anymore. So, how do I remove liba.so from the first device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would think that that question would be on-topic for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

It's certainly ***not*** for [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com).

From the [Help Center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:
>
> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)
>   ...

Comment: Thanks, you saved me some embarrassment. I had just found, and was about to post to, Android Enthusiasts.